# Docker toolbox volume mounting not working on windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10, dockerfile, docker-toolbox

I am new to docker

Here is  my configuration

**Folder Structure**

```
Test :
     - docker-compose.yml
     - Dockerfile
     - www
         - index.html
```

**Docker YML**

```
version: "3"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.16
        command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci','--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.8
        links:
            - db:db
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
volumes:
    persistent:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2.6-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql gd curl
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
```

phpmyadmin dashboard working correctly, But when i enter the web url it shows **403 forbidden error**

When it check the log it shows an error like this :

```
[Mon Sep 02 12:00:44.290707 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 18] [client 192.168.99.1:52312] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
192.168.99.1 - - [02/Sep/2019:12:00:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 508 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
```

and my "/var/www/html" directory was empty. How can i fix it ?

**Update**

I created a file index.php using bash it worked, but i can't locate index.php file on my file system [image: Bash command and browser screenshot]

Please help

If you need any additional info feel free to ask :).

Thanks

Comment: Where is `./www` directory? It should be placed in docker builder context.

Comment: Please check the container's logs - find the respective name/ID with `docker ps` and then inspect them with `docker logs -f ...`.

Comment: do [docker exec -it <container-name> bash] and check if index.html exists in /var/www/html ?

Comment: @bellackn  I updated the question please check

Comment: @Rezwan  no files on there

Comment: that means your Dockerfile has issue, it havent copied www directory to container.

Comment: let me debug it locally,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i figured the issue, i am using docker toolbox so  it only mount  `C:\Users` directory but my project folder is on d drive.  so i have to mount my `D:\projects` directory to vm shared folder. i followed the below steps

1. In Virtual Box under 'Settings' -> 'Shared Folders' added 'projects'
   and pointed it to the location I want to mount. In my case this is
   'D:\projects' (Auto-mount and Make Permanent enabled)
2. Start Docker Quickstart Terminal
3. Type 'docker-machine ssh default' (the VirtualBox VM that Docker
   uses is called 'default')
4. Go to the root of the VM filesystem, command 'cd /'
5. Switch to the user root by typing 'sudo su'
6. Create the directory you want to use as a mount point. Which in my
   case is the same as the name of the shared folder in VirtualBox:
   'mkdir projects'
7. Mount the VirtualBox shared folder by typing 'mount -t vboxsf -o
   uid=1000,gid=50 projects /projects' (the first 'projects' is the
   VirtualBox shared folder name, the second '/projects' is the
   directory I just created and want to use as the mount point).
8. Now I can add a volume to my Docker file like this: '-
   /projects/test/www/build/:/var/www/html/' (left side is the
   /projects mount in my VM, the right side is the directory to mount
   in my docker container)
9. Run the command 'docker-compose up' to start using the mount (to be
   clear: run this command via the Docker Quickstart Terminal outside
   of your SSH session on your local file system where your
   docker-compose.yml file is located).

And i change the docker-compose.yml like this :

```
version: "3"
services:
    www:
        build: 
         context: .
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
        volumes:
            - /projects/test/www:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.16
        command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci','--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.8
        links:
            - db:db
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
volumes:
    persistent:
```

i also updated the oracle vm.
I found this solution from here : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22430#issuecomment-215974613
Thanks bro :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your Dockerfile,

```
FROM php:7.2.6-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite
COPY www/ /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
```

This will copy your www dir to /var/www/html dir inside container, let your web service run.

Comment: Still it shows forbidden error, Do i need to update any settings ?

Comment: I can see phpMyAdmin at localhost:8000, can u write commands u use to run?

Comment: Please Join : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198832/docker-cofiguration-fixing-with-razwan